# Erase a specific character from a given string C++11

Tags: string, c++11, erase

I would try to remove a specific character from a given string in the following code.

```
int main(void){
    string query="a*de*da";
    string org;
    uint8_t rmc='*';

    std::vector<string::const_iterator> wpos;
    for(string::const_iterator itr = org.begin();
        itr!=org.end();
        ++itr){
        if(*itr==rmc){
            wpos.push_back(itr);
        }
    }   

    uint64_t wcnt=0;
    for(auto witr: wpos){
         org.erase( witr-(wcnt++) );
    }   
    query=org;
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

In this code, I would expect that query="adeda" however,  I got an error

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_string<char>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >)’
org.erase(witr-wcnt);
```

My experimental setting is g++ 4.9.2 of devtoolset-3 on CentOS6.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From C++98 to C++11, the signature of `std::string::erase` changed from

```
iterator erase(iterator p)
```

to

```
iterator erase(const_iterator p)
```

It seems like g++4.9.2 still uses the old version. Your example should compile if you change `string::const_iterator` to `string::iterator`.